# Как сделать прокрутку внутри слайда (swiper js)?

Tags: javascript, swiper

У меня есть фуллпейдж сайт на swiper.js. Как я могу сделать прокрутку внутри слайда, если он полностью не помещается в экран?

Answer (score 0):

Добавь элементу класс swiper-no-swiping, и теперь при скролле на нём, не будет происходить переключение (тестил на телефоне, точную реализацию на пк пока что не знаю, возможно это она и есть, но нужно что-то корректировать). Также можно добавить css-свойство overflow-y: scroll;